# why does my editText doesn't presents the right output in android?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm a beginner in android programming and  I'm trying to write a simple calculator with 3 editText fields.
2 of them are used as inputs and the 3rd as the output result.
when I click on the "+" button I expect it to output the sum of the 2 numbers.
but I get a weird number instead for example 2+3 = 2.131230724E9
I tried resolving in over the net but couldn't find that specific problem.... thanks...

```
final double tf1 = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(R.id.editText1));
final double tf2 = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(R.id.editText2));


    Button btplus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);


    btplus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            double tf3;
            tf3 = tf1 + tf2;
            EditText result = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            result.setText(String.valueOf(tf3));
        }
    });
```

Comment: have you initialized your editexts. `R.id.editText1` referring to int value in R.java

Comment: This is not getting the number from the `EditText` -> `String.valueOf(R.id.editText1)` and that's your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R.id.editText1` is referring to int value in `R.java`.

You need to initialize EditText first in `onCreate` . If you don't want the final modifier declare EditText's as class member

```
   final EditText ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
   final EditText ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
   final EditText result = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
```

Then

```
    Button btplus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);  
    btplus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        double tf3;
        double tf1 =Double.parseDouble(ed1.getText().toString());
        double tf2 =Double.parseDouble(ed2.getText().toString());
        tf3 = tf1 + tf2; 
        result.setText(String.valueOf(tf3));
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your code:

```
final double tf1 = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(R.id.editText1));
final double tf2 = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(R.id.editText2));
```

you are not taking the value of the EditText, but instead the reference to the objects. You need to change this for something like this

```
final double tf1 = Double.parseDouble(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString());
final double tf2 = Double.parseDouble(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2)).getText().toString());
```

Also, you should include this lines in the OnClick method of the button, so it Will take the current values when you click in the button.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and now for some reason it gets stuck without displaying any of the components (white screen only, that turns black and freezes until it gets forced to shut down...) any idea why...?

Comment: Have you made any more changes? Could you paste the full onCreate method, to check if something else is wrong? Also, paste the logcat output, as this can help find the problem

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
final double tf1 = Double.parseDouble(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString());
final double tf2 = Double.parseDouble(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2)).getText().toString());
Button btplus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
btplus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v)
{
double tf3;
tf3 = tf1 + tf2;
EditText result=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
result.setText(String.valueOf(tf3));
}
});
}'

Comment: Problem solved with Raghunandan's answer. Thank you very much for your help! appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this :

```
result.setText(String.valueOf(tf3));
```

Use this :

```
result.setText("" + tf3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

final double tf1 = Double.parseDouble(editText1.getText().toString());
final double tf2 = Double.parseDouble(editText2.getTExt().toString());
```

R.id is just a reference integer and that is why you are getting odd numbers when adding the two id integers together, not the actual value in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

```
final double tf1 = Double.parseDouble(edittext1.getText().toString());
final double tf2 = Double.parseDouble(edittext2.getText().toString());


Button btplus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);


btplus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        double tf3 = 0;
        tf3 = tf1 + tf2;
        EditText result = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        result.setText(String.valueOf(tf3));
    }
});
```